# How to union polygons with common ID in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, union

I have a shapefile with lots of polygons and I need to union all polygons which have the same identifier-id into a new (multi-)polygon, ideally with the same identifier-id on another (new) layer.

Is there a simple way I can do this automatically in QGIS?

Answer (score 10):

Do a dissolve on the ID field.

Answer (score -1):

Using Postgis this can be done very easily within less time ..
steps for that

1. upload your shapefile in postgis
2. get a list of total geometries available:

```
lst = some_function('select geom from tableName')
```

1. iterate over table
   fetch each geometry and use:

```
g3 =  ST_Union(geometry g1, geometry g2);
```

1. and the final geometry you got will the union of all.

I don't whether this is the Best for You.. But I would have follwed this..